# RenderTargetBitmap Bold's Text

Tags: wpf, vb.net, bitmap

I am currently trying to make an application that involves sliding controls on and off the screen. Essentially, imagine a mobile desktop that has pages to the left and the right, that's what my application looks like, except there are only 2 pages. I currently slide the pages using a storyboard and an ItemsControl as well as a RenderTargetBitmap of the page that is leaving the screen. The problem is, that the RenderTargetBitmap appears either stretched a little or as if all the text on the control has suddenly become bolded. You can see the bold effect in the image below:

[image: Bold Problem]

This is what the page looks like when it is not rendered as a bitmap:

[image: Standard]

The other control, that slides in from the right, has no such problem. It is always the RenderTargetBitmap that has this problem. I generate the Bitmap with this function:

```
Public Function RenderBitmap(Element As FrameworkElement) As RenderTargetBitmap
    Dim TTopLeft As Double = 0
    Dim TTopRight As Double = 0
    Dim TWidth As Integer = CInt(Element.ActualHeight)
    Dim THeight As Integer = CInt(Element.ActualWidth)
    Dim DPIX As Double = 96.0
    Dim DPIY As Double = 96.0

    Dim PxlFormat As PixelFormat = PixelFormats.Default
    Dim ElementBrush As New VisualBrush(Element)
    Dim Visual As New DrawingVisual()
    Dim DC As DrawingContext = Visual.RenderOpen()

    DC.DrawRectangle(ElementBrush, Nothing, New Rect(TTopLeft, TTopRight, TWidth, THeight))
    DC.Close()

    Dim ExportBitmap As New RenderTargetBitmap(TWidth, THeight, DPIX, DPIY, PxlFormat)
    ExportBitmap.Render(Visual)
    Return ExportBitmap
End Function
```

Which is displayed in a Rectangle:

```
    Dim rtb As RenderTargetBitmap = RenderBitmap(PageViewer)
    RectangleVisual.Fill = New ImageBrush(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb)) With {.Stretch = Stretch.Fill}
```

The rectangle in XAML is:

```
    <Border x:Name="BorderVisual" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Rectangle x:Name="RectangleVisual"/>
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
        <Border.CacheMode>
            <BitmapCache EnableClearType="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderAtScale="1.0"/>
        </Border.CacheMode>
    </Border>
```

Am I missing some property that should be set to true? A quality property? I can't find anything. Is there a better method that I should be using to create the bitmap?

Thanks!

EDIT 1: Using `Stretch = None`

[image]

EDIT 2: Problem solved, my heights and widths in the function were around the wrong way...Problem has been plaguing me for weeks. Sometimes its the little things that count!

Comment: Try using `Stretch.None` in `RectangleVisual.Fill`

Comment: Oh, now I feel really really really stupid. I played around changing the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` values...Then I realised that I had them around the wrong was as you can see above. :D